# Vertically Centering (customized) margin note relative to the paragraph it's part of

Tags: vertical-alignment

With the help of someone on this forum, I was able to create a customized margin note, that's rotated 90 degrees and highlighted.

I'd love it if this was centered on the paragraph it was part of, purely for ease of reading/clarity what it's meant to refer to.

MWE:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
%\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.9in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}


\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}


\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{lipsum}


%%%%%
% MY MARGIN NOTES %
\newlength{\minboxwidth}
\newlength{\maxboxwidth}
\newlength{\oldmaxboxwidth}
\newcommand*{\notefont}{\linespread{1}\normalsize\raggedright}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mymarginnote}[1]{%
    \setlength{\minboxwidth}{2\baselineskip}% minimum width of the text
    \setlength{\maxboxwidth}{\textheight}% maximum width of the text
    \setlength{\oldmaxboxwidth}{\maxboxwidth}%
    \@tempcnta=10 % max. iterations
    % Now we iterate to get a good boxwidth not extending 
    \@whilenum \@tempcnta > \z@\do {%
        \advance\@tempcnta\m@ne
        \settoheight{\@tempdima}{\parbox{\maxboxwidth}{\notefont #1}}%
        \settodepth{\@tempdimb}{\parbox{\maxboxwidth}{\notefont #1}}%
        \ifdim \dimexpr\@tempdima + \@tempdimb\relax <\marginparwidth
        % total height of box is less than \marginparwidth -> can reduce width
        \oldmaxboxwidth=\maxboxwidth
        \maxboxwidth=\dimexpr (\maxboxwidth+\minboxwidth)/2\relax
        \else
        \ifdim \dimexpr\@tempdima + \@tempdimb\relax >\marginparwidth
        % total height of box is greater than \marginparwidth -> advance width
        \ifdim \maxboxwidth=\oldmaxboxwidth
        % Cannot extend height -> stop and use (to small) width
        \@tempcnta \z@
        \else
        % try to increase width
        \minboxwidth=\maxboxwidth
        \maxboxwidth=\oldmaxboxwidth
        \fi
        \else
        % Don't think, that this would ever happen, but if, it would be perfect
        \@tempcnta \z@
        \oldmaxboxwidth=\maxboxwidth
        \fi
        \fi  
    }
    %\reversemarginpar% Use left margin of oneside document
    \marginpar{\hfill\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\parbox{\oldmaxboxwidth}{\notefont #1}}}%
}
\makeatother
%%%%%

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\definecolor{aqua}{RGB}{0,255,255}
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{ {\sethlcolor{#1} \hl{#2}} }



%% Creates command \colormargin that combines \mymarginnote and \hl 
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\colormargin}[1]{\mymarginnote{\hlc[aqua]{#1}}}

\makeatother
%%

\makeatletter%
\long\def\@makefntext#1{%
    \parindent 1em\noindent \hb@xt@ 1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1%
    \ifnum\the\spacefactor<3000.\fi}
\makeatother

% START DOCUMENT %

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]\colormargin{margin note abc def}

\end{document}
```

This results in this:
[image]

How can I vertically center `\colormargin` here?

Thanks!